# In a select element, is it required that the value attribute of each option be unique?

Tags: html

Are the any requirements in the HTML spec that say the `value`s of the `option`s in a `select` must be unique?

My question is about the validity of duplicate `value`s. Ignore all the impracticalities  in the following code block, is the `select` valid?

```
<select id="produce" multiple>
    <option value="2.00">Apple</option>
    <option value="1.50">Banana</option>
    <option value="1.50">Carrot</option>
</select>

<input id="total" type="text">

<script>
    $('#produce').on('change',function(e) {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#produce option:selected').each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $('#total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Should be valid.  You can always run your code through a [validator](http://html5.validator.nu) if you're concerned.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The value of the `option` in the `select` list doesn’t affect the validity of the `select` element.

One thing that you need to keep in mind is that the `id` of an element must be unique for consistency in accessing that element properly. If duplicate `id`s exist for multiple elements the last instance of that `id` will be selected. You definitely need not worry about the duplication of values of the `option`s in the `select` list.

This may even be required too, e.g. the following:

```
<select>
    <option value="fruit">mango</option>
    <option value="flower">rose</option>
    <option value="fruit">pineapple</option>
    <option value="flower">lotus</option>
    <option value="flower">lily</option>
</select>
```

Now if the user selects any of `rose`, `lotus`, or `lily`, the value of the select element will be `flower`, and in case either of `mango` and `pineapple` is selected, the value of the `select` element will be `fruit`. So it’s perfectly OK, and you may need this sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such requirement. All HTML specifications define the `value` attribute simply as having a text (CDATA) value without imposing any restrictions.

This is, of course, just the formal side. It is difficult to imagine a situation where it would make sense to have two `option` elements in the same `select` element with the same `value` attribute. It is formally valid, but if you think you need it, you have probably misanalyzed something.

Comment: OP has a pretty decent example of how you would need 2 `options` with the same `value` :) Though I personally wouldn't make an ordering menu in that manner.

Comment: @Agony, the sketchy example is a good example of a case where you should *not* use the same value. You would get the right price all right, but you would not know whether to deliver bananas or carrots to the customer.

Comment: Haha, see I agree with that. The only way you could find that out is if you pulled the inner HTML, which is always a terrible idea when you have control over the HTML. Like I said, I wouldn't make an ordering menu in that manner.

Comment: :) I realize my example is stupid, hence the statement "Ignore all the impracticalities...". I found Rajesh's example of duplicate `value`s to be a good one. I could see a situation where the developer would only want to check if the user picks either a flower or a fruit.

Comment: I have a perfectly good reason for wanting this - a country dropdown with the most commonly selected countries at the beginning. I want `USA`, `Canada`, `UK` then a blank space, then all the other countries *including* the ones I already have at the top. It seems to be working ok so far and in both Chrome and Safari it stays selected to the one I chose. Our third/fourth 'most popular' country is New Zealand and UK and I don't want people to have to scroll to the end of the list on a phone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this `select` is valid. The value of `option`s do not have to be unique.

[Here's a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/hVgYm/)